# Inserting characters into the middle of an array

Tags: java, arrays

I've got a char array called *encoded* which has a series of char values. I want to insert 3 chars into the middle of the array and keep the remaining chars by pushing them to the next spaces. Is this possible?

Portion of the code I've used as follows just inserts and replaces the next two chars too.

```
    encoded = new char[20];
    encoded = encodeArray.toCharArray();
    for (int x = 0; x < encoded.length; x++) {
        if (encoded[x] == a) {
            encoded[x] = amp;
        } if (encoded[x] == und) {
            for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++) { 
                encoded[x+y] = tilde;
            }
        }
    }
```

Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you try `StringBuffer.Insert()` method here.. I assume you have the index that you want ti inject the 3 chars.

Comment: As @bonCodigo mentioned, using a higher level API is recommended. If you aren't manipulating the mutable structure from multiple threads, however, use `StringBuilder` instead of `StringBuffer`; it is considered the preferred substitute in a majority of situations.

Comment: Considering I have half my project to still complete in only two days I've dropped this one and picked another section to focus on. I just didn't have enough time to figure it out. Hopefully I'll get part marks. Thanks to everyone for their help though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Several points.

First, Java's arrays a relatively low-level data structures. They don't support insertion, etc. And they don't dynamically grow.

In your case, you can manually shift the characters by `n`, but that is loss-less only if the original array had extra `n` slots of capacity.

For manipulating character arrays, look at [`java.lang.StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)

Finally, since we are talking Java, there are certain Unicode *codepoints* that require two Java `char`s. One of the many reasons to use higher level operations when manipulating character sequences.

Comment: +1 for better explained and robust performance structural advise. :-)

Comment: @Dilum Ranatunga Looking at that I like what it does and it does more or less keep the array effect I was looking for. Problem is I converted the char array to that and it just runs out of memory now when I try to insert the three ~'s.

Comment: So you can't insert a char into a charArray, but you can replace chars that are in the charArray with a different char?

Comment: @user1588867 -- do you have the problem even if you pre-allocate some extra space in the buffer? See this constructor: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#StringBuilder(int) . You would allocate then append the original string.

Comment: @Sunny -- that is effectively correct, but I find it easier to think of java arrays as fixed size containers where the values are mutable. You can do whatever to the contents, but you can't grow the arrays themselves. You could have 'inserted' with a small helper function if you had intentionally pre-allocated extra space. Note that if the entire array isn't the string/series, you'd need your own end-of-string indicator or maintain the actual length in a peer variable.

Answer (score 1):

You should push your remaining chars right 3 places(**if overflow then you will loose the 3 chars from end**) as below:

```
   if (encoded[x] == und) {
        //move the chars 3 places right first
        for (int z = encoded.length-4; z > x; z--) { 
            encoded[z+3] = encoded[z];
        }
        //then fill the 3 places as you want
        for (int y = 0; y < 3 && x+y < encoded.length; y++) { 
            encoded[x+y] = tilde;
        }
    }
```

If you want to increase the length of your char array by `3` (to retail all old characters) then you need to redefine a a char array of size as `encoded.length+3` and copy the element using `System.arraycopy(Object src,int srcPos, Object dest, int destPos, int length)` and then insert the three characters in between.

Comment: How does that move work? Isn't encoded.length-3 going to return the entire array size minus 3? The und value might be significantly deeper into the array than that.

Comment: @user1588867: I updated the answer with an additional check on length in your second loop as: `for (int y = 0; y < 3 && x+y < encoded.length; y++) {` to make sure it doesn't cross the char array length.

Comment: @user1588867: If you notice, its a loop, which moves the elements from the back of the array starting from `encoded.length-4` (updated answer) and goes up to `x`. `x` is the index from where your want to insert the chars, right? This loop is making place for 3 chars at that index. Still doubtful/unclear, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Using a String instead of a charArray will allow you to use [replaceAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

Comment: Believe me, I'd love to use a simple replaceAll. The assignment I'm working on is kind of strict in it's spirit of keeping everything quasi-tokened down to char values.